# ESXI PCIe GPU Passthrough does not allow for CUDA

Tags: vmware-esxi, passthrough, graphics-processing-unit, cuda

I am trying to do cuda development in an ESXI environment, so I installed a Quadro 5800 in my ESXI machine (Dell T7500).  I did passthrough to the Windows 7 VM that I will be doing development in, but when I run GPU-Z or a cuda program, CUDA is not detected.  What could be causing the GPU to show up in device manager, but not function as a CUDA device?
I installed the CUDA development tools which include the driver.  Later, I will be trying to install windows directly on the system to see if it functions correctly.

Edit:
I tested the GPU in a windows install directly on the machine and it functioned correctly.  This leads me to believe it is a problem with the passthrough.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this, I have a similar issue

Comment: I gave up and just put the cards in a different computer without ESXI.